# How to properly use mysql MONTH() and YEAR() in codeigniter active record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter Active Record Class trying to get the month and year part of a column wherein the dataType is DATE

```
$this->db->where('mo', 'MONTH(so_date)');
$this->db->where('yr', 'YEAR(so_date)');
```

Code above gives me this. The MONTH() AND YEAR() are enclosed within single quotation marks.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytbl 
WHERE `mo` = 'MONTH(so_date)'
AND `yr` = 'YEAR(so_date)'

//so_date looks like this : 2013-04-15
```

What am I doing wrong here or what do I change so as not to get the quotation marks? When I remove the quotes and try to run it in PHPMYADMIN the query gives me exactly what I want.

Comment: Is `so_date` the name of your date field, or a variable being passed to the query? If the latter then surely it should look like `$this->db->where('mo', 'MONTH(' . $so_date . ')');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

`$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter.

If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will **not try to protect your field** or table names with **backticks**.

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

so do something like :

```
$this->db->where('mo', 'MONTH(so_date)' , FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where('mo = MONTH(so_date)');
```